# Visual Studio C++ Preprocessor behavior changed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor

I'm using Visual Studio C++ Preprocessor to preprocess some files **which are not** C or C++ files (I find it very convenient).

Recently I upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to 2015 and found out that the preprocessor behavior **slightly changed**. Some text that works on VS2010 gives an error on VS2015 and vice versa.

To illustrate the difference, here are two one liner files, `ok2010.c` and `ok2015.c`, and the preprocessing command line running with VS2010 and VS2015:

ok2010.c:

```
#define X `0'`'
```

ok2015.c:

```
#define X `0'`'`'
```

Preprocessing on VS2010:

```
c:\>cl -E ok2010.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ok2010.c
#line 1 "ok2010.c"

c:\>cl -E ok2015.c
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ok2015.c
#line 1 "ok2015.c"
ok2015.c(1) : error C2001: newline in constant
```

Preprocessing on VS2015:

```
c:\>cl -E ok2010.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ok2010.c
#line 1 "ok2010.c"
ok2010.c(1): error C2001: newline in constant

c:\>cl -E ok2015.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ok2015.c
#line 1 "ok2015.c"
```

I guess that the preprocessor handles differently *tick* (`'`) and *backtick* (`` ` ``), and expects them to be balanced. When they are not balanced it reports a newline in a quoted constant expression.
VS2010 ignores backtick entirely and expects only the ticks to be balanced, so this behavior makes sense.
However,  I can't make sense of VS2015 behavior since it works only when both ticks and backticks are **not** balanced...

Any idea?

Comment: MSVC preprocessor was never the most stable or standard conforming thing. If you can, switch to another CPP (like GNU's cpp.exe, available in Cygwin).